# jhbuild run required GnomeDesktop

Tags: gnome

After successful build with jhbuild I tried to follow steps from [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/BuildGnome): call killall gnome-weather and get that process is not found (may be it is ok, I think) and run module gnome-weather. It says me:

```
(org.gnome.Weather.Application:23477): Gjs-WARNING **: JS ERROR: Error:   
Requiring GnomeDesktop, version none: Typelib file for namespace
'GnomeDesktop' (any version) not found
@resource:///org/gnome/Weather/Application/js/app/city.js:21
@resource:///org/gnome/Weather/Application/js/app/window.js:23
@resource:///org/gnome/Weather/Application/js/app/main.js:36
@/home/greenekatherine/jhbuild/install/bin/gnome-weather:6

JS_EvaluateScript() failed
```

I clean and rebuild then but get the same problem. May be I should install something additional for GnomeDesktop? I have no idea, because build doesn't produce any message about it. It is my first attempt to work with jhbuild and I would be thankful for some help.

My system is Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit version.

Answer (score 0):

If you check city.js, you will find this line:

> src/app/city.js:const Gnome = imports.gi.GnomeDesktop;

So you need something related to javascript and gnome introspection.

Try to search appropriate package using 'apt-cache search javascript introspection'. Do you have gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 or gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 installed?